# What do you call the feeling you get when you're satisfied to the point of nausea?

Tags: single-word-requests

So you're craving something, say a particular chocolate or sex with one very attractive person that you desire. Take the sexual encounter one for example. You sleep with the person so many times until you are fulfilled. But it gets somewhat "nauseating" to enjoy that thing again (the sex or the chocolate) because you've overindulged earlier.

Now what is that feeling called, the feeling of being overly "satisfied" or "quenched" to the point of nausea?

I wouldn't say what I'm looking for is ***satisfaction*** or ***quench***. Is there a more specific term?

Example sentence:

> "I've been eating T-bone steak all day yesterday. I had leftovers today, but I couldn't eat them - I'm just so ____ towards (or from) steak right now."

Comment: For chocolate, maybe.  But for a sexual encounter with a very attractive person you desire?  Does that really happen?  Actually, now that I think of it, not even for chocolate.

Comment: Consider [sated](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sated), though to work as a fill-in-the-blank for your example you should replace *towards* with *with*.

Comment: I'd say 'scunnered with' but colloquial scots may not be what you're looking for. :)

Comment: (for food) the answer is "stuffed".  for sexuality, maybe something like "overindulged"; phrases like "I just went way over the top" also give the suggestion you're getting at.

Comment: "You took too much, man. You took too much, too-much." [NSFW](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZGxwOaniQG4)

Comment: Yet another option is _surfeited_. According to Merriam-Webster, the [noun form of _surfeit_](http://www2.merriam-webster.com/cgi-bin/mwdictadu?book=Dictionary&va=surfeit) can mean (among other things) "an intemperate or immoderate indulgence in something (as food or drink" or "disgust caused by excess." The [verb form of _surfeit_](http://www2.merriam-webster.com/cgi-bin/mwdictadu) means "to feed, supply, or give to surfeit."

Answer (score 23):

You can actually use the word ***"[sick](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sick)"***.

> 3. *(sick of)* Intensely annoyed with or bored by (someone or something) as a result of having had too much of them:

Using your example.

> I've had four steaks over the last couple of days and now I'm sick of them.

Comment: "If music be the food of love, play on,/
Give me excess of it; that surfeiting,/
The appetite may sicken, and so die." —*Twelfth Night*, I.i.1-3

Comment: But "sick" could also mean that you're physically sick from eating them (a la, food poisoning).

Comment: @E.Groeg I don't think a native English speaker would ever interpret the sentence that way. It would be "I've had four steaks over the last couple of days, and now I'm sick." To be *sick of* something is different from being *sick*, because being *sick of* something is a specific phrase that indicates you've had too much of it.

Comment: Sick, like barfing rainbows.

Answer (score 20):

Consider ***[cloy](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cloy)***:

> **verb (used with object)**
>
> (1) to weary by an excess of food, sweetness, pleasure, etc.; surfeit; satiate.
>
> **verb (used without object)**
>
> (2) to become uninteresting or distasteful through overabundance

You could say things like:

> - I soon found sex with her cloying.
> - A diet of steak soon cloys.
> - I'm just so cloyed by steak right now.

Comment: Hmm.  Certainly a good word.  But. That word originated in Middle English and I doubt its been heard much since, outside of poetry.  In particular, I'd be rather bemused if anyone used any of your three example sentences in conversation.

Comment: @davidbak, well here's an Ngram comparing "cloy", "satiate", and "surfeit": https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=satiate%2Ccloy%2C+surfeit&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csatiate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccloy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csurfeit%3B%2Cc0 . "Cloy" loses. But I use it at least.

Comment: @davidbak, and the Corpus of Contemporary American English gives a dozen or so examples from 1990-2015 (http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/).

Comment: I see that ["had it up to here"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=satiate%2Ccloy%2Csurfeit%2Chad+it+up+to+here&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csatiate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccloy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csurfeit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chad%20it%20up%20to%20here%3B%2Cc0) is giving "cloy" a run for its money .... thanks for the ngram link, that's fun.

Comment: The "Corpus of Contemporary American English" is a resource I hadn't seen, thanks.  But of the 13:  2 uses of "Cloy" as a proper noun, one from a poem (I excluded that), one from a song (goes with the poem), and one from a quote of an Australian (and you know how _they_ talk) - leaves only 8.  But I suppose some of the examples left I would in fact possibly hear in conversation.  And not be bemused.  So I stand corrected.  But really, your example 3: You say "you" could say things like that, but would _you_?

Comment: I have most often heard the adjective "cloying" rather than the verb "cloy" and Ngram suggests it's at least an order of magnitude more common this way: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cloy%2Ccloying&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccloy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccloying%3B%2Cc0 I say at least because many instances of "cloy" appear to be either a typo for "clay" or a family name. I also think of "cloying" as usually meaning sickly *sweet* specifically, which seems to be a common usage in the 1988-2000 results.

Comment: Agree with @nedibes - I wouldn't think of *cloying* as archaic at all, but the most common modern use is definitely that of sickly sweetness.  A favourite example comes from Star Trek DS9 when Quark describes human root-beer as : *"...so bubbly and cloying, and happy."*

Comment: Is it always used as *cloy by*? I mean the preposition.

Comment: @Ustanak, it actually seems like "cloyed with" is more common. See here, but take the results with a grain (or shaker) of salt: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cloyed+with%2C+cloyed+by%2C+cloyed+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccloyed%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccloyed%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccloyed%20on%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 10):

I think you could use ***[satiated](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/satiated):***

> - satisfied, as one's appetite or desire, to the point of boredom.

- I'm so satiated with steaks right now!!

Comment: [Leptin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leptin) (from Greek λεπτός *leptos*, "thin"), the "satiety hormone"

Answer (score 6):

[*overindulge*](https://www.google.com/search?q=over%20indulged%20definition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) : "have too much of something enjoyable, especially food or drink." -Google

Last night I *overindulged*. If I so much as look at another steak I'll throw up.

Answer (score 5):

I would use ***[overfull](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/overfull)***.

> excessively full

- "I really thought I wanted those 3 cheeseburgers, but now I'm overfull of meaty goodness. My tummy hurts."

Comment: That's why they're called *sliders*.

Answer (score 3):

In British English, when referring to food, this is usually called being or feeling [stuffed](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stuffed)

> (of a person) having eaten enough or too much:
>   "No more for me thanks - I'm stuffed."

Comment: I'm curious how you will use this in the sexual context.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use the informal *[overdose](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/overdose)* for some of those situations.

> verb 2. to take an excessive dose or give an excessive dose to

It obviously has roots in the medical emergency of a drug overdose, but everybody understands when I tell a personal story

> Yes, SweeTarts used to be my favorite candy, but one time my parents gave me a big box of them and I overdosed (or ODed) on them. I find them less appealing now.

Answer (score 1):

*Gorged* has specific connotations to do with food as it specifically references the feeling of closeness in the throat causing people to feel nauseated.

"I've been eating T-bone steak all day yesterday. I had leftovers today, but I couldn't eat them - I'm just so gorged on steak right now."

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gorged

Answer (score 0):

I see suggestions from the previous answers/comments which come very close and perhaps one or more of them fits your purpose.

You may also use "saturated".

> I am just so *saturated* with steak right now.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/saturated

Answer (score 0):

It's more of an idiom than a single word, but you might use **couldn't eat another bite**

For instance:

> Would you like some more of the stew?
>
> No, thank you, I couldn't eat another bite.